# How to know whether the intent is finished or not?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-studio

I want to know after my application call an intent, it is finished or not. If it is finished, then call another activity. How can do this? Thank you.

```
 Intent callintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
 callintent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + num));
 startActivity(callintent);
 if(callintent is finished)
 {
     startActivity(new Intent(MakeCall.this, NewActivity.class));
 }
```

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: İt is not work for me.. Any other way to do this ?

Comment: another way is using broadcastreceiver.

Comment: u can use startactivityforResult  to initiate call and then in OnActivityForResult u can pass the intent..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PhoneStateListener** helps    when a phone call is ended, come back to the original activity (actually, it just restart the activity).

**MainActivity .java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

final Context context = this;
private Button button;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCall);

    // add PhoneStateListener
    PhoneCallListener phoneListener = new PhoneCallListener();
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this
        .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    // add button listener
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1234567890"));
            startActivity(callIntent);

        }

    });

}

//monitor phone call activities
private class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    private boolean isPhoneCalling = false;

    String LOG_TAG = "LOGGING 123";

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
            // phone ringing
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);
        }

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
            // active
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "OFFHOOK");

            isPhoneCalling = true;
        }

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
            // run when class initial and phone call ended, 
            // need detect flag from CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "IDLE");

            if (isPhoneCalling) {

                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "restart app");

                // restart app
                Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                    .getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                        getBaseContext().getPackageName());
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);

                isPhoneCalling = false;
            }

        }
    }
}

}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonCall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="call 1234567890" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: I solved my problem but this is also a good solution. Thank you